# AWS EKS NodeGroup "Create failed": Instances failed to join the kubernetes cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, amazon-eks

I am able to create an EKS cluster but when I try to add nodegroups, I receive a "Create failed" error with details:
"NodeCreationFailure": Instances failed to join the kubernetes cluster

I tried a variety of instance types and increasing larger volume sizes (60gb) w/o luck.
Looking at the EC2 instances, I only see the below problem. However, it is difficult to do anything since i'm not directly launching the EC2 instances (the EKS NodeGroup UI Wizard is doing that.)

How would one move forward given the failure happens even before I can jump into the ec2 machines and "fix" them?

> Amazon Linux 2
>
> > Kernel 4.14.198-152.320.amzn2.x86_64 on an x86_64
> >
> > ip-187-187-187-175 login: [   54.474668] cloud-init[3182]: One of the
> > configured repositories failed (Unknown),
> > [   54.475887] cloud-init[3182]: and yum doesn't have enough cached
> > data to continue. At this point the only
> > [   54.478096] cloud-init[3182]: safe thing yum can do is fail. There
> > are a few ways to work "fix" this:
> > [   54.480183] cloud-init[3182]: 1. Contact the upstream for the
> > repository and get them to fix the problem.
> > [   54.483514] cloud-init[3182]: 2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for
> > the repository, to point to a working
> > [   54.485198] cloud-init[3182]: upstream. This is most often useful
> > if you are using a newer
> > [   54.486906] cloud-init[3182]: distribution release than is
> > supported by the repository (and the
> > [   54.488316] cloud-init[3182]: packages for the previous
> > distribution release still work).
> > [   54.489660] cloud-init[3182]: 3. Run the command with the
> > repository temporarily disabled
> > [   54.491045] cloud-init[3182]: yum --disablerepo= ...
> > [   54.491285] cloud-init[3182]: 4. Disable the repository
> > permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
> > [   54.493407] cloud-init[3182]: will then just ignore the repository
> > until you permanently enable it
> > [   54.495740] cloud-init[3182]: again or use --enablerepo for
> > temporary usage:
> > [   54.495996] cloud-init[3182]: yum-config-manager --disable

Comment: Are you deploying the instances to a private VPC without a NAT gateway (no internet access)?

Comment: have you tried adding nodes with eksctl?

Comment: @paltaa good point. eksctl works great (suggesting that permissions are not an issue), however eksctl does not allow v1.18 yet so I had to move to UI and/or aws cli instead

Answer (score 17):

In my case, the problem was that I was deploying my node group in a private subnet, but this private subnet had no NAT gateway associated, hence no internet access. What I did was:

1. Create a NAT gateway
2. Create a new routetable with the following routes (the second one is the internet access route, through nat):

- Destination: VPC-CIDR-block Target: local
- **Destination: 0.0.0.0/0 Target: NAT-gateway-id**

3. Associate private subnet with the routetable created in the second-step.

After that, nodegroups joined the clusters without problem.

Comment: Note that NAT gateway should be created in public subnet. Otherwise instances in private subnet won't be able to connect to internet and we will get same NodeCreationFailure error.

Answer (score 12):

Adding another reason to the list:

In my case the **Nodes** were running **in a private subnets** and **I haven't configured a private endpoint** under *API server endpoint access*.

After the update the nodes groups weren't updated automatically so I had to recreate them.

Comment: I was able to get mine to work by converting the private subnets to public.  I realize not everyone will want to do this, but if you do, here is how: just add a route to an internet gateway.  If you have any public subnets,then you will aready have an internet gateway.  Go to VPC > Subnets > Select your subnet and vew details.  Then find the route table and select it.  Click Actions > Edit Routes, then click Add Route.  Add a route to 0.0.0.0/0 via the existing internet gateway.  This makes the subnet public, and then the EC2 instances can access the API server for your cluster.

Comment: Hi @Alejandro703, I think I would prefer to avoid exposing my worker nodes on public subnets - that will open them to different types of attack vectors.

Comment: Totally understood.  After writing that commebt, it occurred to me that you should be able to add a route in the route table directly from the private subnet to the public API endpoint without exposing the entire subnet.

Answer (score 10):

I noticed there was no answer here, but about 2k visits to this question over the last six months. There seems to be a number of reasons why you could be seeing these failures. To regurgitate the AWS documentation found here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html

> - The aws-auth-cm.yaml file does not have the correct IAM role ARN for
>   your nodes. Ensure that the node IAM role ARN (not the instance
>   profile ARN) is specified in your aws-auth-cm.yaml file. For more
>   information, see Launching self-managed Amazon Linux nodes.
> - The ClusterName in your node AWS CloudFormation template does not
>   exactly match the name of the cluster you want your nodes to join.
>   Passing an incorrect value to this field results in an incorrect
>   configuration of the node's /var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig file, and the
>   nodes will not join the cluster.
> - The node is not tagged as being owned by the cluster. Your nodes must
>   have the following tag applied to them, where  is
>   replaced with the name of your cluster.

```
    Key Value kubernetes.io/cluster/<cluster-name> 
    Value owned
```

> - The nodes may not be able to access the cluster using a public IP
>   address. Ensure that nodes deployed in public subnets are assigned a
>   public IP address. If not, you can associate an Elastic IP address to
>   a node after it's launched. For more information, see Associating an
>   Elastic IP address with a running instance or network interface. If
>   the public subnet is not set to automatically assign public IP
>   addresses to instances deployed to it, then we recommend enabling that
>   setting. For more information, see Modifying the public IPv4
>   addressing attribute for your subnet. If the node is deployed to a
>   private subnet, then the subnet must have a route to a NAT gateway
>   that has a public IP address assigned to it.
> - The STS endpoint for the Region that you're deploying the nodes to is
>   not enabled for your account. To enable the region, see Activating and
>   deactivating AWS STS in an AWS Region.
> - The worker node does not have a private DNS entry, resulting in the
>   kubelet log containing a node "" not found error. Ensure that the VPC
>   where the worker node is created has values set for domain-name and
>   domain-name-servers as Options in a DHCP options set. The default
>   values are domain-name:.compute.internal and
>   domain-name-servers:AmazonProvidedDNS. For more information, see DHCP
>   options sets in the Amazon VPC User Guide.

I myself had an issue with the tagging where I needed an uppercase letter. In reality, if you can use another avenue to deploy your EKS cluster I would recommend it (eksctl, aws cli, terraform even).

Answer (score 4):

I will try to make the answer short by highlighting a few things that can go wrong in frontline.

**1.** Add the IAM role which is attached to EKS worker node, to the `aws-auth` config map in kube-system namespace. [Ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html)

**2.** Login to the worker node which is created and failed to join the cluster. Try connecting to API server from inside using nc. Eg:  `nc -vz 9FCF4EA77D81408ED82517B9B7E60D52.yl4.eu-north-1.eks.amazonaws.com 443`

**3.** If you are not using the EKS node from the drop down in AWS Console (which means you are using a LT or LC in the AWS EC2), dont forget to add the `userdata` section in the Launch template. [Ref](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/introducing-launch-template-and-custom-ami-support-in-amazon-eks-managed-node-groups/)

```
set -o xtrace
/etc/eks/bootstrap.sh ${ClusterName} ${BootstrapArguments}
```

**4.** Check the EKS worker IAM node policy and see it has the appropriate permissions added. `AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy`  is a must.

**5.** Your nodes must have the following tag applied to them, where cluster-name is replaced with the name of your cluster.
`kubernetes.io/cluster/cluster-name: owned`

I hope your problem lies within this list.

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/resolve-eks-node-failures/

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I had the NAT Gateway in my private subnet. Then I moved the NAT gateway back to public subnet which worked fine.

Terraform code is as follows:

```
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "gw" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.dev-vpc.id
  tags = {
    Name = "dev-IG"
  }
}

resource "aws_eip" "lb" {
  depends_on    = [aws_internet_gateway.gw]
  vpc           = true
}

resource "aws_nat_gateway" "natgw" {
  allocation_id = aws_eip.lb.id
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.dev-public-subnet.id
  depends_on = [aws_internet_gateway.gw]
  tags = {
    Name = "gw NAT"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Auto Scaling group logs showed that we hit quote limit.
`Launching a new EC2 instance. Status Reason: You've reached your quota for maximum Fleet Requests for this account. Launching EC2 instance failed.`
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/fleet-quotas.html

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is here network subnets they are public and private subnets. Check your Private subnets are added to NAT Gateway. If it is not added, add  Private subnets to NAT Gateway and also check public subnets are attached to the Internet gateway.

Answer (score 1):

Your AMI needs to have `kubelet` installed. Some AMIs don't have it by default.

In my case, all networking and IAM related resources were configured correctly but my nodes weren't able to join the cluster.

The problem was that although I chose an AMI type and image from EKS documentation, the AMI did not seems to have `kubelet` installed.

I SSH-ed into the node and confirmed that the node was healthy, but the kubernetes agent wasn't running.

Solution was to choose the default AMI with `kubelet`installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a tag to your private subnets where the worker nodes are deployed.

kubernetes.io/cluster/<cluster_name> = shared

Answer (score 0):

we need to check what type of nat gateway we configured. It should be public one but in my case i configured as private.

Once i changed from private to public the issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and any provided solutions worked. After some investigation and running:

```
journalctl -f -u kubelet
```

in log I had:

```
Error: failed to run Kubelet: running with swap on is not supported, please disable swap! or set --fail-swap-on flag to false
```

So naturally, the solution seems to disable swap with

```
swapoff -a
```

And then it worked fine, node has been registered and output was fine when checked with `jounralctl` and `systemctl status kubelet` .

Answer (score 0):

It will almost definitely not be this but check your labels to make sure you are not setting one to an illegal value.

At some point in the past you could set [this well-known label](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/labels-annotations-taints/#node-role-kubernetes-io-control-plane) `node-role.kubernetes.io/your-custom-role` in the nodegroup labels.

Now it correctly breaks kublet when it is starting up with:

```
Failed to validate kubelet flags" err="unknown 'kubernetes.io' or 'k8s.io' labels specified with --node-labels: [node-role.kubernetes.io/mycustom]\n--node-labels in the 'kubernetes.io' namespace must begin with an allowed prefix (kubelet.kubernetes.io, node.kubernetes.io) or be in the specifically allowed set (beta.kubernetes.io/arch, beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type, beta.kubernetes.io/os, failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region, failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone, kubernetes.io/arch, kubernetes.io/hostname, kubernetes.io/os, node.kubernetes.io/instance-type, topology.kubernetes.io/region, topology.kubernetes.io/zone)"
```

Source Code ([x](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/da0a1a05b9364ff0d875faa6912613d15443e6ef/cmd/kubelet/app/options/options.go#L168))

Also see:

- [Some context on `node-role.kubernetes.io/role` problems](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/39112)
- [Most recent (2021) decision on the `node-role.kubernetes.io/role` debate](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/75457#issuecomment-925767628)
- [Undocumented `kubernetes.io/role` label in kubectl](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/da0a1a05b9364ff0d875faa6912613d15443e6ef/staging/src/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/describe/describe.go#L5444-L5462)
- [Where Documentation for `kubernetes.io/role` died](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/35904)